# Navbar Dropdown expands Nav instead of hovering over

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `nav` that has an internal `dropdown`, but when I pop the drop down it expands the entire `nav`.  I know I'm missing a class or some HTML but I can't seem to reconcile what I'm missing.

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap shadow">
    <a className="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="/">
        <i className="fa fa-home"></i> Seeker
    </a>
    <input className="form-control form-control-dark w-100 mw-100" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
    <ul className="navbar-nav px-3">
        <li className="nav-item dropdown">
            <a id="navbarDropdown" className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <i className="fa fa-user"></i>
            </a>
            <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Mike</a>
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Log Out</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

It does get wrapped like this because it's a React Component named `Menu` on its own.

```
<div className="container-fluid">
    <Menu />
    <div className="row mt-2">
        <Sidebar />
        <div className="container ml-n2 mt-2">
            <h1><i className="fa fa-shield"></i> Admin</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anybody lead me to what I'm missing?

Comment: You're not using `react-strap` and using Bootstrap's jquery?

Comment: That is correct @AkberIqbal.  The primary reason for that is because the designers on the overall team aren't React developers so it provides cross-team compatibility.  However, that shouldn't have any bearing on the Bootstrap markup except that I'm not using a Component wrapper.

Comment: i am unable to replicate this at https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9l2cht - can you share this behavior somewhere?

Comment: @MikePerrenoud are you just toggling the `show` class manually? Bootstrap applies a `position: absolute` inline, along with some other styles through their js. If you don't want it to affect its container height, it'll need to be `absolute`.

Comment: @sallf so I'm not kicking off the `show`, I'm just letting the attributing do that (i.e. it's getting picked up by default to pop).

Comment: @AkberIqbal that's actually doing exactly what I'm referring to.  When expanding the Profile it doesn't pop that menu over the top; rather it expands inside the menu.

Comment: @MikePerrenoud you should either use [reactstraps dropdown components](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/) or if you're using normal bootstrap, you'll need to [include the js](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) (they use popper.js).

Comment: @sallf please add your answer.  It was in fact that the `popper.js` library was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following CSS would get you the pop-up effect that you're looking for:

```
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu{
  position:absolute; right:0;
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu{ left:0; }
}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9l2cht)